# XCUITest recording fails with "Please select a scheme where "XCUITodo" is the executable"

Tags: xcode8, xcuitest

I'm using Xcode 8 to automate my application.
I get started by downloading an existing code: **XCUIToDo** project. I opened the project in Xcode, and when I click on the Record button, I'm seeing a warning message *"Please select a scheme where "XCUITodo" is the executable"* and the record feature does not start.
Please let me know where I'm missing.

TIA

Answer (score 22):

Ensure that an executable is selected for your UITest scheme.

1. Select Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes
2. Select your UITest scheme in the list
3. Select Edit
4. Select the Info tab under Run
5. Ensure that the required Executable is selected

Answer (score 16):

The problem is not on the UITest schema or target. When starting to record, the main schema (the one which runs the application) needs to be selected regardless if you have your UI tests on a different schema.

Answer (score 11):

Click on Project Root, then Targets -> XCUIToDoUITests target.  From the General tab, check the "Target Application" setting under Testing section.  The value in the dropdown should match the XCUIToDo target.

Answer (score 0):

For me after making sure everything mentioned above is selected properly, I had to choose same scheme (as selected under `info` in `edit scheme`) next to device selection on the top.